# IIS Reverse/Forward proxy to locahost with port number

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I created a reverse/forward proxy rule in IIS so that it rewrites all requests from `maps.mysite.com` to `localhost:8080`.

This sort of works. But for some reason it doesn't seem to take the port it should rewrite to into account.

If I goto: `maps.mysite.com:8080` then I get the correct page.
But if I goto: `maps.mysite.com`, then it doesn't work. This gives me a **500 Internal Server Error**.

I configured the proxy like this.

Why isn't it working when I leave out the port number?

[image]

Comment: Show the complete 500 error page please. Besides, FRT can tell you more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi It seems to be a 500.52 error. A gzip compression issue. I followed a tutorial (see link), but that didn't do the  trick. When I disable Compression on my IIS site, then it works. Not sure if that is problematic to have that disabled - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/iis-acting-as-reverse-proxy-where-the-problems-start/ba-p/846259